# 5* difficulty C# LINQ expression for generic class's property

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Cheers, I'm trying to create generic **function** that returns **dynamic LINQ expression** as follow.

```
// creating baseClassInstance...
var baseClassInstance = new BaseClass<GenericClass>(new GenericClass(true));

// getting expression, func, and finally the field's value
var expression = GetBoolEqualsExpression<GenericClass>("SomeBool");
var func = expression.Compile();
var result = func.Invoke(baseClassInstance);

public class BaseClass<T>
{
    public T GenericInstance;
    public BaseClass(T genericInstance)
    {
        this.GenericInstance = genericInstance;
    }
}

public class GenericClass
{
    public bool? SomeBool;
    public GenericClass(bool someBool)
    {
        this.SomeBool = someBool;
    }
}
```

Currently I'm facing the problem with **GetBoolEqualsExpression**:

```
    private System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<BaseClass<Tgeneric>, bool>> GetBoolEqualsExpression<Tgeneric>(string propertyName) where Tgeneric : class
    {
        var parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(BaseClass<Tgeneric>), propertyName);
        var property = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Field(parameter, propertyName);
        var target = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(true);

        var expConverted = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(property, typeof(bool));
        var exp = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(expConverted, "Equals", null, target);
        var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<BaseClass<Tgeneric>, bool>>(exp, parameter);

        return lambda;
    }
```

If I leave the 1st row as `Parameter(typeof(BaseClass<Tgeneric>)`... then 2nd row with `property` fails with

```
System.ArgumentException: Instance field 'SomeBool' is not defined for type 'BaseClass`1[GenericClass]'
```

If I change to `Parameter(typeof(Tgeneric)...` then 7th row with `lambda` fails with

```
System.ArgumentException: 'ParameterExpression of type 'GenericClass' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'BaseClass`1[GenericClass]''
```

**Any help highly appreciated!**

Comment: Second error.  You cannot cast an inherited class to a base class.  So change Func<BaseClass<Tgeneric>> to Func<Tgeneric>

Comment: @jdweng "*You cannot cast an inherited class to a base class*" Er, no.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to access the `GenericInstance` field of `BaseClass`.

This line doesn't work because `parameter` is a `BaseClass<GenericClass>`, not `GenericClass`:

```
var property = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Field(parameter, propertyName);
```

How would you normally access `SomeBool` given a `BaseClass<GenericClass>` called `parameter`? You would do `parameter.GenericInstance.SomeBool`, right? Not `parameter.SomeBool` by itself.

So do the analogous thing with expression trees:

```
var genericInstance = Expression.Field(parameter, "GenericInstance");
var property = Expression.Field(genericInstance, propertyName);
```